# Hardcoded select item/conditionals in Ember hbs

Tags: templates, ember.js, conditional-statements

Instead of tying records to a data list I have a hardcoded list of buttons. What I want is to tie a conditional to the buttons but don't know how. I can when a record gets set to selected item but not with hardcoded values e.g.

`<button class='task data ManagedList'>Agreement Type</button>`

and then the conditional

`{{#if selectedItem}}{{editor/administration/edit-managed-list store=store}}`

want to make it so that when the hardcoded Agreement Type button is clicked the condition if selectedItem is true for this condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but I think that if I follow you, you could do something like this... (I'm using the ember-truth-helpers addon to for the eq helper):

template.hbs:

```
<button {{action "selectItem" "foo"}}></button>

{{#if (eq selectedItem "foo") }}
  conditional content
{{/if}}
```

in component.js, set a property to a value you want to match against:

```
selectedItem: '',

actions: {
  selectItem(val) {
    this.set('selectedItem', val);
  }  
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use closure actions: `<button onclick={{action "selectItem" "foo"}}>` Actions assigned by template modifiers have some tricky edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is basically toggle the selectedItem property which should return bool. 
If in the template you have `{{#if selectedItem}}` then go back to the component context and set the 
1. Add the selectedItem property in the component. E.g. `selectedItem: false`
2. Add an action on the button: `<button class='task data ManagedList' {{action "toggleSelectedItem"}}>Agreement Type</button>`
3. On the component side under the actions hash toggle the property:

```
actions: {
    toggleSelectedItem() {
      this.toggleProperty('selectedItem');
    }
  }
```

This should toggle your selectedItem property between true and false.